# How to implement chained stub in javascript with Jasmine and AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, stubbing

I'm not sure if I'm writing the title correct, but here's what I want to do.

I have this code

```
    var callback = function(result) {
        if(result.count < 5) {
            msg_id = result.msg_id;
            MovieService.getMovies(msg_id, result.count).get(callback, error);
        }

        if(result.movies.length !== 0) {
            setDataToDisplay(result);
        }

        if(result.count === 5) {
            $scope.loading = false;
        }
    }

    MovieService.getMovies(msg_id, 0).get(callback, error);
```

Basically, when user comes in the first time MovieService will be called and it gets called until the `count` equals to 5 times. It's like a recursive loop. Now if I want to test this code, I don't know how to do chained stub in Jasmine. I could do something similar in Mockito.

Here's my test so far.

```
it("should give me the lot of movies", function() {
    var movie1 = new MovieBuilder().withTweetId('8').build();
    var movie2 = new MovieBuilder().withId('3812').withTweetId('8').build();
    var movie3 = new MovieBuilder().withId('3813').withTweetId('8').build();
    var movie4 = new MovieBuilder().withId('3814').withTweetId('8').build();


    movieService = {
        getMovies : function() {
            return { 
                get : function(callback, error) {
                    callback(
                    {
                        'msg_id' : '8',
                        'count' : '5',
                        'movies' : [movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ctrl = controller('MovieTwitterCtrl', {$scope : scope, MovieService : movieService});

    expect(scope.movie_groups[0].length).toBe(4);
    expect(scope.msg_id).toBe('8');
});
```

But if I want to test the second, third, fourth and fifth call. How do I do that? Does Jasmine  offer something like Mockito? Or how do I do that in pure javascript?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/), which is a library that provides methods for spys, stubs and mocks and is compatible with Jasmine.

In order to automatically invoke your callbacks, you would use `stub.yields()` or `stub.yieldsTo()`. You've also got `spy.getCall(n)` that will let you verify the way your method was called during the `n`th time. Sinon is written in a way that stubs are also spies... so if you create a stub for your movieService, you'll have access to both `yields()` and `getCall(n)`.